# Feller Condition in the Heston Model

Tags: stochastic-volatility, heston, finite-difference-method

I understand that for MC simulations we require the Feller Condition otherwise the simulation becomes unstable when approximating the events when $v_t<0$, but for semi-analytical solution and using FDM, why is the Feller condition still required?

In the FDM case, you discretise $v \in (0,3)$, and the vol of vol will never bring $v<0$ anyway.

Then why in papers authors make sure the feller condition is satisfied when using FDM and semi-analytical solution when in reality it's not satisfied more often than not?